# Why Arabic Noto font (or other Arabic fonts) are rendering incorrectly in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, fonts, arabic

I am rendering Arabic text using the [Google Noto Sans Serif Font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/), and it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the alignment is off *by a lot* in some places.

[image]

My HTML document is very simple, it's essentially this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: Noto;
        src: url(./arabic.ttf);
      }

      body {
        font-family: "Noto";
      }

      .line {
        white-space: pre;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body dir='rtl'>
    the arabic text...
  </body>
</html>
```

All it does is add the Google Noto Font to the `body` and then there's a bunch of `<div class='line'>arabic text...</div>` lines.

However, in the picture above, there are two what feel like **glaring** problems.

First is, the text does not seem to be *visually aligned* properly. It feels *jumbled* and *jagged* rather than having a clear baseline. Some parts the main horizontal stretch of the word or characters is even *way above* or *way below* the "average" placement of the horizontal baseline.

Second, I am not skilled at Arabic atm, but it appears some of the characters are shifted slightly so as not to connect cursively in a nice clean way, like the rendering algorithm is messing up in certain situations.

Am I just misunderstanding how this is supposed to look, or are these visual problems actually there? If these are defects, how do I fix it and make the Arabic text cleaner and more horizontally aligned, through CSS or otherwise.

If it's at all relevant, I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate a PDF from the HTML, which is what that image is.

Comment: Instead of this "the arabic text..." please paste at least one of the sentence where this issue happens. We need to be able to reproduce it to help you, howver we may not need to know how to read an type Arabic. As a first step, are you sure the same font is used for all the glyphs in this text? Can you double check this from your dev-tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in conversion (wkhtmltopdf) and not in CSS. Why don't you use a browser like Chrome to convert your HTML into PDF? It works better for Arabic texts. Arabic texts usually need a higher line-height than normal e.g. `1.6`

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

On a side note, I'd recommend [Vazir](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font) font. It renders texts containing diacritics optimally.